# remove array object from localStorage Angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, local-storage

In my Ionic Framwork App i have a cart array stored in the angular localStorage
like this

```
localStorage.setItem('mycart', JSON.stringify(items));
```

and i retrieve the localStorage Array like this

```
var cart_items = JSON.parse(localStorage.mycart);
```

**Output**

```
[{"id":"1","item_name":"pepsi","qty":"2"},{"id":"2","item_name":"coke","qty":"2"},
{"id":"3","item_name":"fanta","qty":"3"}]
```

i am trying to remove an product item using the below code. but it does not work, it removes the entire item in the array

```
for ( var i = 0; i < cart_items.length; i++ ) {
    if ( cart_items[i].id === $removeId ) { //
       cart_items.splice(i,1); 
    }
}
localStorage.mycart= JSON.stringify(cart_items );
```

it removes all the items in the array

Comment: Could you precise where "$removeId" come from ?

Comment: `$removeId  // the id of the item`

Comment: I knew it is the id of the item, but could you add "where" it is initialized ?

Comment: i pass the value of id through parameter like `function($removeId )`
and the removeId contains the value of item id

Comment: You shoudn't use $ when naming your variables. $ is a reserved char for the angular build in services. I actually don't get why it don't work. I mean it should work. Could you provide a code snippet or a plunker with the problem ? It would be easier for me to help your with that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me finally

```
var cart_items = JSON.parse(localStorage["mycart"]);
for (i=0;i<cart_items.length;i++)
  if (cart_items[i].id == 'id_1') cart_items.splice(i,1);
  localStorage["mycart"] = JSON.stringify(cart_items);
```